# Collect many Firebase Child IDs to Array List and delete them with Database Reference in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to collect many IDs to Array List in Java. I make a Broadcast Receiver to get some IDs. It's working but I want to delete a child in Firebase Realtime Database with I got IDs. This is My Broadcast Receiver...

```
public BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String MassageID = intent.getStringExtra("MassageID");
        lists = new ArrayList<String>();
        lists.add(MassageID);
        
        DeleteIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
```

This is My Delete Method. I want to Delete Values in Firebase database with Array List.

[image: This is my databse]

```
private void OnClickListener() {
    DeleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        
            DatabaseReference DeleteMassages = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CommunicationSystem").child(UserRoom);

            DeleteMassages.child(lists.toString).removeValue();
        }
    });
}
```

```
DeleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DatabaseReference DeleteMassages = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CommunicationSystem").child(UserRoom);

        DeleteMassages.child(lists.toString).removeValue();
    }
});
```

I am trying this code but it's not working.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how `UserRoom` is initialized? It'd probably also help if you debug the problem locally and tell us the result. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: If you're new to debugging, The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.